# Named searches in Vim?

Tags: vim

Is there a way to save a search pattern to a register and then conjure it up with some quick command?

I'm thinking of the way vim uses named registers with q and @, and named marks with m and '.

Comment: @user406289, that is a good point.

Comment: Vim questions belong here. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25925/vim-questions-so-or-su

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Enter the search pattern in a buffer somewhere, then yank/delete it into a register.  Use ctrl-r+x, at the search prompt (/), to retrieve register x.

If you already searched for the pattern, use `:let @x=@/` to assign it to register x.

Comment: It's worth nothing that you can use `:let @a=@/` to store the last search in another register rather than pasting it into your document.